# Is there a way to change the font for reference tip in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, fonts

How to change the font for content in red frame ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

> Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors

[image]

Change the top combo box to "CodeLens" as shown in the screenshot. You can then set the font and colour of various CodeLens features.

[image]